# Make dropdown to drop up when theres no space at bottom ALPINE JS and TAILWINDCSS

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have a date picker component made with a tailwind and alpine js, I used [this](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/datepicker-with-tailwindcss-and-alpinejs) as my reference to my date picker. My problem is the mobile responsiveness when I'm on a small device the date picker just overflows in the remaining space at the bottom. is there any way to add like a smart dropdown that goes up when there's no space at the bottom?

I also tried putting media queries when in small devices, but it doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: It's good to know what you've used as a reference, but you'll still need to show some of your actual code ideally. Otherwise we're guessing a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to solve this issue, would be to calculate the position of your element relative to the viewport. For that you'd use

```
const pos = element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

and then you could calculate the remaining space to the top / bottom like

```
const offsetTop = pos.top
const offsetBottom = window.innerHeight - pos.bottom
```

When opening the datepicker you have to run this code and decide whether your element will fit within the pixel-value stored in `offsetBottom`, otherwise you open it upwards or some other logic.